# Generate a random value automatically after each 5 sec in PHP

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a random function after each 5 sec and want to print that. But I am not able to do that. My code snippet is:

```
    $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());
    echo $time;
    echo "<br/>";
    while (($time+5) < date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time()))
    {
        $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());
        echo $time;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo rand(3,10);
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript to ease your life.

Comment: you can do it in javascript very easily

Comment: You want to execute this script via CLI or in a browser, so if the difference between two requests is more than 5 seconds then generate a new random value?

Comment: I want to print that value automatically after each 5 sec

Comment: @user3003367 can you use js?

Answer (score 0):

what about this..

```
    // current time
    echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a') . "\n";

    // sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(5);

    // wake up !
    echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a') . "\n";
    echo rand(3,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**in PHP:**

```
$count_for_print = 10;

for($i=1; $i<=$count_for_print; $i++)
{
    echo $i." : ".date('d-M-Y g:i:s A')." : ".rand(3,10)."<br/>";
}
```

**in JS :**

```
<script>

window.setInterval(function(){
  do_task();
}, 5000);



function do_task()
{
    var rand_num = get_rand(3, 10);

    var html = "<br/>";
    html += rand_num;

    var output_div = document.getElementById('output_div');
    output_div.HTML = output_div.HTML+html;
}

function get_rand(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}
</script>

<div  id="output_div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while (1==1) {
    echo rand(3,10);
    sleep(5);
}
```